# R Extracting unique values and sorting each row in a data frame

Tags: r

If I have a data frame as below how do I extract the unique values and sort each row of the Targer column?

`df <- data.frame (ID = c(5,377,6), Target = c("CD125, CD1, CD1, CD123", "CD3, CD1, CD1", "") )`

I have tried using split, sort and unique on a singel string and it sort of works.
But I can’t apply it to each row.

`s2 = "CD125, CD1, CD1, CD123"`

`s2 <- strsplit(s2, ",")`

`s2 <- sort(unlist(s2))`

`s2 <- unique(s2)`

Comment: If you do not expect unique values per id, you could use `strsplit()` on the column `Target` of `df`: `sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(df$Target, ","))))`. Is it the expected output?

Comment: Based on your example, could you please provide the exact expected output for the entire dataframe `df`?

Answer (score 0):

Using sapply on all columns except first (which is not character)

```
sapply(df[,-1,drop=F],function(x){
  sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(x,", ",))))
},simplify=F)

$Target
[1] "CD1"   "CD123" "CD125" "CD3"
```